# Necessary condition to be closed Irreducible subspace

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $X=\text{Spec}(R)$ where $R$ is a commutative ring with unity. If $Y\subset X$ is a closed subspace that is irreducible, then $Y = V(P)$ for some $P\in X$.

Proof. Since $Y$ is closed, $Y = V(I)$ for some ideal $I\subset R$. Need to show $I$ is prime ideal. Let $f,g\notin I$. Then consider $D(f)\cap Y$ and $D(g)\cap Y$. Assume they are both nonempty. Then they are nonempty open sets in $Y$ and as $Y$ is irreducible, $D(f)\cap D(g)\cap Y = D(fg)\cap Y$ is nonempty. But if $P\in D(fg)\cap Y$ then $I\subset P$ and $fg\notin P$ which implies $fg\notin I$.

The problem is I don't know how prove  $D(f)\cap Y$ is nonempty. I don't know if it's helpful information but I found that such $f,g$ are non-units.
But still don't know. Could you give any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assume $I$ to be a radical ideal (since $V(I) = V(\sqrt{I})$). Then notice that $\sqrt{I} = \bigcap_{\mathfrak p \in V(I)} \mathfrak p$, therefore $f\notin I$ iff there is a $\mathfrak p\in V(I)$ with $f\notin \mathfrak p$.

Comment: No, but $Y = V(\sqrt{I})$, thus $\sqrt{I}$ being prime is all you need.

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid I can't afford the time to write down a detailed solution but do allow me to provide you with a sketch of the natural line of argumentation for establishing this result. Consider an arbitrary (does not even need to be necessarily commutative) ring $A$ together with the notations:

- $\mathscr{Id}_{\mathrm{b}}(A)$ for the set of all *bilateral* ideals of $A$.  We shall also employ the symbol $I \leqslant_{\mathrm{b}} A$ to denote the fact that $I \in \mathscr{Id}_{\mathrm{b}}(A)$ is a bilateral ideal of $A$.
- $\mathscr{Spec}(A)$ for the *prime* spectrum of $A$, i.e. the set of all prime ideals of $A$.
- $\mathscr{V}(X)=\left\{P \in \mathscr{Spec}(A) \mid X \subseteq P \right\}$ for any subset $X \subseteq A$.
- $\mathrm{Id}\left(\mathscr{X}\right)=\begin{cases}\bigcap \mathscr{X}, &\mathscr{X} \neq \varnothing \\ A, &\mathscr{X}=\varnothing\end{cases},$
  for any subset $\mathscr{X} \subseteq \mathscr{Spec}(A)$.
- $\mathscr{R}=\left\{I \in \mathscr{Id}_{\mathrm{b}}(A) \mid \sqrt{I}=I\right\}$ for the set of all *semiprime* (this is the general terminology) ideals, or *radical* ideals (as they are called in the commutative setting).
- $\mathscr{Za}_{\mathrm{f}}(A)=\left\{\mathscr{V}(X)\right\}_{X \subseteq A}$ for the set of all *Zariski* closed subsets of the prime spectrum.
- $G.H=\left\langle GH \right\rangle$ as the *subgroup* product (the subgroup generated by the *subset* product $GH=\{xy\}_{\substack{x \in G\\ y \in H}}$) for any two additive subgroups $G, H \leqslant A$. When $I \leqslant_{\mathrm{s}}A$ is a *left* ideal and $J \leqslant_{\mathrm{d}}A$ a *right* one we have in particular that $I.J \leqslant_{\mathrm{b}}A$ is a bilateral ideal.

One proceeds by first setting up the following:

> **Proposition 1.** For any bilateral ideal $I \leqslant_{\mathrm{b}} A$ we have $\mathrm{Id}\left(\mathscr{V}(I)\right)=\sqrt{I}$ (the radical of $I$ which is defined in the general case of not necessarily commutative rings and reduces to the well-known construction in the commutative case). Similarly, for any subset $\mathscr{X} \subseteq \mathscr{Spec}(A)$ we have $\overline{\mathscr{X}}=\mathscr{V}\left(\mathrm{Id}\left(\mathscr{X}\right)\right)$.

and continues with the following:

> **Corollary.** The maps given by:
> \begin{align*}
> \mathscr{R} &\to \mathscr{Za}_{\mathrm{f}}(A)\\
> I &\mapsto \mathscr{V}(I)\\
> \mathscr{Za}_{\mathrm{f}}(A) &\to \mathscr{R}\\
> \mathscr{F} &\mapsto \mathrm{Id}\left(\mathscr{F}\right)
> \end{align*}
> are *mutually inverse antiisotonic maps* when ordering both domains by inclusion.

From the corollary we infer in particular that any closed subset $\mathscr{F} \subseteq \mathscr{Spec}(A)$ must be of the form $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{V}(I)$ with $I \in \mathscr{R}$ being a *semiprime* (radical) ideal. With these observations in place, it is easy to establish:

> **Proposition 2.** $\mathscr{F} \in \mathscr{Za}_{\mathrm{f}}(A)$ is *irreducible* if and only $\mathrm{Id}\left(\mathscr{F}\right) \in \mathscr{Spec}(A)$ is prime.

*Proof.* For the direct implication, consider the irreducible closed subset $\mathscr{F} \subseteq \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and set $P=\mathrm{Id}\left(\mathscr{F}\right)$ such that $P \in \mathscr{R}$ is radical and $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{V}(P)$ by virtue of the above corollary. Since $\mathscr{F}$ is irreducible it is nonempty and therefore $P \neq A$, hence $P$ is a *proper* bilateral ideal (bear in mind that $\mathscr{V}(A)=\varnothing$). Consider now arbitrary $I, J \leqslant_{\mathrm{b}} A$ such that $I.J \subseteq P$. This entails $\mathscr{V}(I.J)=\mathscr{V}(I) \cup \mathscr{V}(J) \supseteq \mathscr{V}(P)$ and by virtue of irreducibility further leads to $\mathscr{V}(P) \subseteq \mathscr{V}(I)$ or $\mathscr{V}(P) \subseteq \mathscr{V}(J)$. By applying the $\mathrm{Id}$ operator and reversing the inclusions we infer $P=\sqrt{P} \supseteq \sqrt{I} \supseteq I$ or $P=\sqrt{P} \supseteq \sqrt{J} \supseteq J$. This means that $I \subseteq P$ or $J \subseteq P$ and thus proves that $P$ is prime.

For the converse implication it suffices to show that $\mathscr{V}(P)$ is irreducible whenever $P$ is prime. Obviously we have $P \in \mathscr{V}(P) \neq \varnothing$. Consider now two *relatively* closed subsets $\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{G} \subseteq \mathscr{V}(P)$ such that $\mathscr{V}(P)=\mathscr{F} \cup \mathscr{G}$. As subsets closed relatively to an *absolutely* closed subset, $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$  are in their own turn *absolutely* (Zariski) closed and thus we can write $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{V}(I)$ respectively $\mathscr{G}=\mathscr{V}(J)$ for some bilateral ideals $I, J \leqslant_{\mathrm{b}}A$. We have that $\mathscr{V}(I) \cup \mathscr{V}(J)=\mathscr{V}(I.J)=\mathscr{V}(P)$ whence $P \in \mathscr{V}(I.J)$. This leads successively to $I.J \subseteq P$ - therefore either $I \subseteq P$ or $J \subseteq P$ as $P$ is prime - and signifies that $\mathscr{V}(P) \subseteq \mathscr{V}(I)=\mathscr{F}$ or $\mathscr{V}(P) \subseteq \mathscr{V}(J)=\mathscr{G}$. We conclude by noticing that we are led to either $\mathscr{V}(P)=\mathscr{F}$ or $\mathscr{V}(P)=\mathscr{G}$ which entails the irreducibility of $\mathscr{V}(P)$. $\Box$